# UITableViewCell for headerview not loading subviews from storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have used a simple prototype cell from storyboard for adding header view to my table view. I added some labels in cell and give specific tag to every label, but while accessing it returns me nil value for [cell viewWithTag :] method.(I have not created a custom class for cell) I am using following method

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UITableViewCell * headerView = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HeaderView"];

    UILabel * lblVenueName = (UILabel *)[headerView viewWithTag:100];
    lblVenueName.text = @"Test Venue";

    return headerView;
}
```

for above code the value for lblVenueName always return nil.

Comment: You have to check if `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns an object or if you have to create a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this problem in XCode 7.0 beta 5 (7A176x). I suppose it's a bug. I've checked in debugger and turns out that cell contentView does not have any subviews at runtime.
If you are designing for some specific screen size then this workaround may help you. Switch to the base values like this:
[image: Screen size checking screenshot]

Then in attributes inspector check that both "installed" options are checked on all views that you need and their superviews (for example for all views in prototype cell, table view and it's superview):

[image: Screenshot of "installed" options]

After that you can return to your specific screen size and `viewWithTag()` will return correct values.

Answer (score 0):

> (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
>
> Return Value
>
> A UITableViewCell object with the associated identifier or nil if no such object exists in the reusable-cell queue.

So I'm guessing that method returns nil for you :) Try a version that takes a indexPath :)

Comment: Actually I am getting the HeaderView's object from dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method, but  [headerView viewWithTag:100] returns me nil label.

Comment: Can you print the view hierarchy for the headerView? :)

Comment: You can type in console:
'po [headerView recursiveDescription]'